# Full Rank Matrix can't be zero.

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{align}
A\in R^{M \times N}, \;\; x \in R^N \\
x \neq 0 \\
\\
if \qquad A\;is\;Full\;Rank,\qquad \{Ax = 0\}\;can\;not\;be\;acheived?
\end{align}
Where can I find more explanation for this?

Comment: This is obviously false when $M<N$.

Comment: A nontrivial solution $x\neq 0$ for $Ax=0$ exists if the columns of $A$ admit a linear dependence relation.  As @Frank says, if $M\lt N$, we cannot avoid there being a linear dependence among columns even if the rows are linearly independent (and thus rank$(A) = M$ is "full" rank).